# Android KeyPad with Call and Send Message

Tags: android, android-keypad

I need the Keypad which is similar to Android OS Contact Keypad , Which has Calling and Messaging functionality and i have seen several inputtype like Phone ,number etc But they dont have calling and messaging functionality.

Can somebody suggest me how to customize keypad or Android has just input type ?

Comment: you are asking for some heavy coding.. try out samples provided by android sdk itself [for ref](http://jayxie.com/mirrors/android-sdk/resources/samples/SoftKeyboard/index.html)

Comment: We dont any such default keypad in android OS ?

Comment: What do you you mean by **We dont any such default keypad in android OS** there is samples .. Just open existing projects from samples.. search for softKeyboard and you will get it..